# Writing a formula ... IF more than one picklist field (of 10 fields) has a non-blank value

Tags: formula, parameters

Hello and Thanks in advance,

How do I write a formula to fire as true, if more than one (of 10) **different** picklist **fields** has a non-blank value?  If have tried ...

```
(
IF(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Field_A__c,"")) +
IF(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Field_B__c,"")) +
IF(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Field_C__c,"")) +
IF(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Field_D__c,""))
// and 6 more fields
)))))
> 1
```

I receive an error of **Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 1**

I have used this before with checkboxes w/ success but the line is
IF( Checkbox_Field_A__c = TRUE, 1 , 0 ) +

Thanks again,
Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IF() function in the formula needs 3 parameters to evaluate: the first one is a logic that evaluates to true or false, second argument/statement execute if the logic evaluates to true and the third one to execute if the logic evaluates to false.

So in case, you would need to do what you did for a single picklist for all the 10 fields.

```
IF( Checkbox_Field_A__c = TRUE, 1 , 0 )
```

Using the above, your new formula should be

```
IF(
(IF(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Field_A__c,""),1,0) +
IF(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Field_B__c,""),1,0) +
IF(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Field_C__c,""),1,0) +
IF(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Field_D__c,""),1,0)
// and 6 more fields)
> 1, true, false)
```

Comment: You should never need to compare a checkbox to true/false in a formula, nor calculate `IF(..., true, false)`. Both of these patterns are seen frequently but just waste characters.

Comment: The question was to fire the formula as `true` hence my answer.

Comment: You are missing the point. `IF(condition, true, false)` will output exactly the same value as `condition`.

Comment: Got you now. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is:

```
IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

You need value arguments, not just the condition. Likely you meant:

```
IF(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Field_A__c,""), 1, 0)
```